# How can I reach parent module variable from "required" module in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-modules

I want to reach login information from submodules. How can I From subModules can we reach parent module's, callee's variables?

I take out of function wrapped
like

> loginInformation = {
>      logged:false,
>      name:'',
>      surname:''
>   }

It gave "not function" error.

Comment: more code would make it alot easer to respond to this question.

Comment: no need any code dude, I want to access parent module from submodule. For now on I solved my issue by using another module, which I call it from app.js as "loginInformation = require('service/login');" and then I can access all properties of login module from another module. But i dont think it is right way to do.

Comment: you can save login information in [Titanium.App.Properties](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)

Comment: @adnan please answer this question, so I can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save login information in [Titanium.App.Properties](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)